# Angular 9: Error while "Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...": Identifier directly after number

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I just updated my Angular project from version 8 to 9. As I have to support the IE 11 browser, the target is "es5".

After the update I am getting the following error while "Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading..."

> [1m[31mAn unhandled exception occurred: C:\myproject\polyfills-es5.9b276c87455e9832d96d.js: Identifier directly after number (1:354893)[39m[22m
> [1m[31m[39m[22m

package.json

```
{
"name": "myproject",
"version": "0.0.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.11",
    "@datorama/akita": "^5.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "^3.0.1",
    "cronstrue": "^1.94.0",
    "croppie": "^2.6.5",
    "css-element-queries": "^1.2.3",
    "highcharts": "^8.1.2",
    "highcharts-angular": "^2.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
    "jquery-ui-touch-punch": "^0.2.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^9.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.0",
    "srcdoc-polyfill": "^1.0.0",
    "stacktrace-js": "^2.0.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^9.2.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.10",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.1.11",
    "@asciidoctor/core": "^2.2.0",
    "@asciidoctor/reveal.js": "^4.0.1",
    "@cartant/tslint-config-rxjs": "^2.0.6",
    "@datorama/akita-ngdevtools": "^5.0.3",
    "@types/browser-sync": "^2.26.1",
    "@types/ckeditor": "^0.0.46",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "@types/jqueryui": "^1.12.13",
    "@types/license-checker": "^25.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.157",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.14",
    "@types/request": "^2.48.5",
    "ajv": "^6.12.2",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "dependency-cruiser": "^9.8.0",
    "license-checker": "^25.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "rxjs-tslint-rules": "^4.33.3",
    "saml-idp": "^1.2.1",
    "stylelint": "^13.6.1",
    "stylelint-checkstyle-formatter": "^0.1.2",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^8.0.2",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "^3.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "^4.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^20.0.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^3.18.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "tsc-silent": "^1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "tslint-microsoft-contrib": "^6.2.0",
    "tslint-sonarts": "^1.9.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3",
    "vega": "^5.13.0",
    "vega-embed": "^6.9.0",
    "vega-lite": "^4.13.1"
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "lib": [
        "dom",
        "es2020"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
    ]
},
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
}
```

"npm outdated" gives

[npm outdated gives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Bz9.png)

Any hint what the solution could be?

Answer (score 0):

Some additional information:

`polyfills-es5.<some hash value>.js` is including its own file name at the end as a JavaScript expression. Here's the end of the file (watch the end of line 1, not the comment in line 2)

```
{preventExtensions:function(t){return c&&o(t)?c(i(t)):t}})}},[[4,0]]]),polyfills,es5.e52fb6e508fabacaf778.js;
//# sourceMappingURL=polyfills-es5.e52fb6e508fabacaf778.js.map
```

The compilation error occurs if and only if the hash value begins with a number.

Setting `sourceMap: false` in angular.json seems to prevent the error, the expression that contains the file name is not generated in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem on my project, I solved setting outputHashing to none (angular.json).
Someone has a news on this error? I couldn't find any issue on github angular project, neither any other article on web.